# Inherited class cannot find resource.layout properly

Tags: c#, android, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm writing an application in Xamarin.Android. I have another, core application, where I store some classes and views, and I'd like to inherit an Activity from it. Everything goes fine when building the project, but when starting the app, it throws an exception.
Snippet from the base class:

```
namespace Company.Core.Android
{
    public class MenuableFragmentActivity : SlidingFragmentActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout Company.Core.Android.Resource
        Console.WriteLine("runs correctly until this point");
        SetBehindContentView (Company.Core.Android.Resource.Layout.menu_main);
```

The MainActivity in the inheriting app looks like this:

```
using Company.Core.Android;

namespace Company.Bite.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "App.Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity :MenuableFragmentActivity
    {
        int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        var something = Core.Android.Resource.Layout.menu_main;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that the something variable can easily reach the resource from the core, but when I deploy the application, an exception is thrown (that ID belongs to menu_main):
[image: Exception]

I think the application searches for the menu_main in the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file instead of searching at the fully qualified name (Company.Core.Android...) 
I'm stuck with this, does anyone knows, how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "core application", the `Company.Core.Android` project, do you mean that it is an **Android Library Project**?

Comment: No, that is also an Android Application (Blank App (Android)), I need that for demonstrational purposes... I was thinking about making it a Library, but in that case, when I want to create a demo, I need a new project for it.